# OpenZeppelin Governor quorumNumerator question

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, dao, voting

I may have some misunderstanding of OZ's Governor contract's QuorumNumerator and how to determine if a member of the DAO's has enough tokens/voting power to reach quorum. Please help! Thanks.

For testing my deployment, I had set a high quorumNumerator and now that I'm pretty satisfied that everything is working, I dropped it to a more reasonable level of 1% of tokens to reach quorum (will prob end up at about 3% eventually). I have an account for testing with more than enough ERC20 tokens by itself to reach that quorum but the vote is always defeated - and I'm the only one voting!

The setup is that I preminted 1,000,000,000 (1 billion) ERC20 voting tokens and the account I'm using has 12 million of them - so that would be 1.2%. The tokens have been delegated to myself. So my quorum numerator is 1 and my denominator is the standard 100. My proposal is made and my vote goes thru successfully, but the proposal is always defeated. Shouldn't having my user account vote 'Yes' on the proposal be enough to have the vote pass? I'm totally confused - maybe I'm mistaken how this all works. Am I missing something?
Thanks for the help
cb